# Horizontal Scroll Without Holding Shift

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

None of my searches have provided any results.

Is it possible using to create a 'horizontal scrolling' functionality that does not involve holding shift while the user scrolls?

Comment: Try this one: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: i actually just came across it. i'm trying to implement it right now. for whatever reason, even though the demo works, i can't seem to get it to work on my system. i'm even using the exact same jquery library that was mentioned in the demo. no console errors or nothing @jcoder

Answer (score 3):

So I'm 6 years too late, but if someone else comes across this issue...

This worked for me, I was having the same issue and used the javascript found here:
https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/scroll-horizontally-with-mouse-wheel-vanilla-java/

```
const scrollContainer = document.getElementById("yourElement");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
});
```

I did have issues where the trackpad was scrolling the horizontal div too slowly, but I adjusted the code that worked well enough for my purposes:

```
const scrollContainer = document.getElementById("myElement");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    if (evt.deltaY >= -15 && evt.deltaY <= 15) {
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += (evt.deltaY * 40);}
    
    else {
        scrollContainer.scrollLeft += (evt.deltaY * 5);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thing is, you also need to account for other forms of navigation such as mobile touch or arrows. But, yes, this works for desktop with a mouse!

Comment: dang! I tested the mobile touch in firefox responsive design mode, but hopefully it will actually still be functional when I get the website online

Comment: and this code worked in firefox for touch scrolling?

Comment: as far as I can tell, yes, but I have yet to plug my phone in to the computer as an extension and try it on there
https://imgur.com/BW0Xb6L